# Redis storing more than one parameter with Zadd

Tags: redis

I am trying to use Redis for my realtime search queries. After reading the article mentionedb below I tried the python scripts and it worked fine. But in database, I'm having two fields:

> i) country_name
>    ii) country_id

How can I insert the country_id and make it searchable as discussed in the [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/creating-a-simple-autocompletion-service-with-redis-part-one-of-two/).

Answer (score 0):

The elements in a Redis Sorted Set are just strings. You can concatenate the name and id for storage purposes, and after querying you split the string back into fields.

Pseudo example:

```
# Store it
redis.zadd('countries', 0, 'Italy:6379', 0, 'foobar:42', ...

...
# Query
q = redis.zrangebylex('countries', ...
f = q.split(':')

print 'name: {}, id: {}'.format(f[0], f[1])
```